# HTML5 Get input file count on change

Tags: jquery, html

I need to use the html5 File API to get the quantity of files selected in the input file element and set the value in another element.

HTML

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label>Main Image</label>
    <div class="form-text">None Selected</div> 
    <input type="file" class="txtbox" name="proImage" id="proImage" value="" />
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    $fileCount = $(this).files.length;
    $(this).parent('.form-row').find('.form-text').html($fileCount + 'Selected');
})
```

Anyone know where I'm going wrong? All help appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`files` is not a property of jQuery object.

Change this:

```
$fileCount = $(this).files.length;
```

To:

```
$fileCount = this.files.length;
```

You can also minify your selector:

```
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    fileCount = this.files.length;
    $(this).prev().text(fileCount + 'Selected');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hHgEF/

Comment: aha, that's what the original script said to do but because i was doing this in jquery i thought i would need to use it within the brackets. Cheers.

Comment: Also use `multiple="multiple"` attribute on input file element to select more than one file.